# How to change sdk version of application in blackberry

Tags: blackberry, blackberry-eclipse-plugin, blackberry-jde

I am using Eclipse to develop a BlackBerry app for BBOS 6.0. I now want to support BBOS 5.0 instead of 6.0.  How do I do this?

Answer (score 4):

You can develop using just one eclipse, not two (each for a OS version).
And switch the compilation target in it.
To do so, you should click properties of `JRE System Library` on your project and add alternate blackberry JRE through `Installed JREs` - `Add` and point to a folder inside your other installed blackberry JDE.

Then you can switch OS5 and OS6 from `Properties for JRE System Library` window in two clicks.

As for using OS6-specific classes and concepts, you should consider using `#preprocess` and `#ifdef BlackBerrySDK6.0.0` for your code to compile in both 5.0 and 6.0.

Answer (score 1):

The First thing you have to do is to install the jde version 5.0. And compile your code with **version5.0 Jde.**  It will run fine if you haven't used the `Updated API` or `some class which have been added into version 6.0 and later`. Like  `Menuitem` i haven't used it so i dont have clear idea what are the classes is added in Version6.0 you can compare it from the doc. one refrence i am attaching [here see the MenuItemconstructor its for 6.0](http://www.blackberry.com/developers/docs/6.0.0api/net/rim/device/api/ui/MenuItem.html) and this [one for 5.0](http://www.blackberry.com/developers/docs/5.0.0api/index.html)  compare the constructor of the both.

Comment: Thanx for Replay.i had install jde version 5.0. i and also made some code for testing it will run.

Comment: it will run if you dont use any classes which is added into version6.0 or later otherwise it will work fine

Comment: i had created one menu class and this class i am inherits to all other class so is it work?

Comment: can you tell me which constructor you have called..if the constructor you have called `MenuItem(StringProvider text, int ordinal, int priority)` ... it wont work on jde 5.0 else it work